# Change of SEO Url for product and category URL

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, url, magento-2.2.5

Magento version: 2.2.5

The categories are:

level 1

level 1.1

level 1.2

level 2

level 2.1

level 2.2

when I go to level 1.2 the url shows up as mysite/level 1.2

But I expect url to be as mysite/level 1/level 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Are categories actually nested within the parent categories? Your expected result is the default output as you can see on this Luma demo: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/

Women -> Tops -> Jackets points to http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/women/tops-women/jackets-women.html

Comment: I have added weltpixel pearl theme. Is the url issue because of theme?